# Go App engine oauth2 request

Tags: google-app-engine, go, oauth-2.0

I've been trying to implement [OAuth2 for Go](https://github.com/golang/oauth2) with App engine server to server request.

Here is the code (following the example):

```
oauthConf, err := google.NewServiceAccountJSONConfig(
    "./key.json",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense.readonly",
)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

client := http.Client{Transport: oauthConf.NewTransport()}
resp, err := client.Get(urlStr)
...
```

And I get the error message:

> http.DefaultTransport and http.DefaultClient are not available in App Engine.

I'm pretty sure the json.key file is valid as for the other stuff

Googling lead me to understand that it is preferred to use **urlfetch**, but I can't figure out how to make the setup with the oauth2 config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NewServiceAccountJSONConfig` returns a `oauth2.JWTConfig` 
https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/google/google.go#L69-L87

Its `.NewTransport()` you are using:
https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/jwt.go#L86-L88

Defaults to the `http.DefaultTransport`, that is not supported on appengine:
https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/jwt.go#L163-L168

I would go for using the `AppEnigneConfig` instead (if possible). See http://godoc.org/github.com/golang/oauth2/google

```
c := appengine.NewContext(nil)
config := google.NewAppEngineConfig(c, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery")
// The following client will be authorized by the App Engine
// app's service account for the provided scopes.
client := http.Client{Transport: config.NewTransport()}
client.Get("...")
```

Otherwise if you need to use `ServiceAccountJSONConfig`, you probably can, but you'll need to use `urlfetch` `Client` and `Transport`. Have a look how `AppEngineConfig` is set up:   https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/google/appengine.go

Comment: I can't see where I can insert the key.json (or alternative clients credentials + private key) for oauth2

Comment: @MrKlint No, that uses google service accounts in appengine, so it will use the credentials of the appengine project. If you need to use other credentials, you'll have to roll your own. Have a look at https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/google/appengine.go to see how transport and client is setup.